# readability add-on to change all grey fonts to black on all sites

Tags: fonts, readability

I would like to change the grey fonts to black. on all sites. I have trouble reading the gray fonts. Can I change them to black?

Answer (score 0):

There is a Mozilla add-on called [Theme Font and Size Changer](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/theme-font-size-changer/) that allows forcing a font color, amongst other options. You need to use Firefox, of course.